# NSJSONSerialization parses JSON, boolean and number values are null

Tags: objective-c

I use NSJSONSerialization to call a login url which returns a JSON object. This obj has 3 props: ***data*** is obj, ***success*** is boolean(NOT String, indicates login success or not), ***timeout*** is number(NOT String).
The problem is the ***success*** and ***timeout***'s values are null. The data is fine.
I tested this url from html file requiring, it works fine.
What's the problem?

http://screencast.com/t/chDMshKPl

Comment: Post code showing how you are reading the values.

Comment: Please show source JSON.

Comment: This is a HTML5 front-end version of login. It call the same request and works fine. I just want to make a iOS app, but got these null issues. I'm out of work env for 3 days now. When I get back will post the JSON source. Thanks!

Comment: Correct one thing, the ***timeout*** is _boolean_ type.The back-end uses spring-mvc ModelAndView and jackson to parse obj to JSON. Here is the returning JSON when I tested it use html requiring in ff. http://screencast.com/t/pDcC2tZ8j

Comment: Somebody help? This issue is so weird.